# How to have a cross out rectangle in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following tikz style

```
  \tikzset{actor/.style={ rectangle, minimum size=6mm, very thick,
    draw=red!50!black!50, top color=white, bottom
    color=red!50!black!20 }
}
```

and I would like to have an other style which is the same but with a cross out in the rectangle. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Instead of posting code snippets, it's usually preferred to post a complete minimal example document. That saves others the work of having to come up with a test document themselves.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `append after command` in conjunction with the `fit` library to place a `cross out` node (which comes from the `shapes.misc` library) over the `actor` node:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    actor/.style={
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, very thick,
        draw=red!50!black!50, top color=white, bottom
        color=red!50!black!20
    },
    actor crossed out/.style={
        actor, 
        append after command={
            node [
                fit=(\tikzlastnode),
                draw=red!50!black!50,
                thick,
                inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                cross out
            ] {}
        }
    }
}

\node [actor] (a) {A};
\node [actor crossed out, right of = a] {B};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `edge`s in the `append after command` to draw the lines. This does not require any libraries:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    actor/.style={
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, very thick,
        draw=red!50!black!50, top color=white, bottom
        color=red!50!black!20
    },
    actor crossed out/.style={
        actor, 
        append after command={
            [every edge/.append style={
                thick,
                red!50!black!50,
                shorten >=\pgflinewidth,
                shorten <=\pgflinewidth,
            }]
           (\tikzlastnode.north west) edge (\tikzlastnode.south east)
           (\tikzlastnode.north east) edge (\tikzlastnode.south west)
        }
    }
}

\node [actor] (a) {A};
\node [actor crossed out, right of = a] {B};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```