# How to draw MUX 8:1

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib, circuits

I have to draw an multiplexer 8:1 exactly the same as in the picture using Latex.

I followed this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180329/how-to-draw-a-multiplexer-8-to-1-with-circuitikz) but I have trouble adapting it to my image (link and rename inputs).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)coordinate (O)--++(30:1)coordinate (A)--++(90:4)coordinate (B)--++(150:1)coordinate (C)--cycle;
\draw ($(A)!0.5!(B)$)--++(0:1)node[right]{$F$};
\draw ($(O)!0.5!(A)$)--++(-90:1)--++(180:2)node[left]{$b$};
\draw ($(O)!0.25!(A)$)--++(-90:0.5)--++(180:1.75)node[left]{$a$};
\draw ($(O)!0.75!(A)$)--++(-90:1.5)--++(180:2.25)node[left]{$c$};
\foreach \y/\t in {0.1/1,0.2/2,0.3/3,0.4/4,0.5/5,0.6/6,0.7/7,0.8/8} {
\draw ($(C)! \y*1.1 !(O)$)--++(180:1) node[left] {$I \t$};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please show how you try adopt solution in given link! where you have a problem?

Comment: @Zarko My problem is that I don't know how to add text in the Multiplexer (000, 001, 010, ....), to link the inputs and resize width of the box (Multiplexer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a version using `pic`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  multiplexer/.pic = {

    % frame
    \draw[pic actions] (0, 0) coordinate (-SW) -- ++(30 : 1.5)
    coordinate (-SE) -- ++(90 : 4) coordinate (-NE) -- ++(150 : 1.5)
    coordinate (-NW) -- cycle;

    % output
    \coordinate (-output) at ($(-SE)!0.5!(-NE)$);

    % select
    \foreach \x/\lbl in {0.25/A,0.50/B,0.75/C} {
      \coordinate (-\lbl) at ($(-NW)!\x!(-NE)$);

    }

    % input
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{1.0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{4.5}
    \foreach \i in {0,1} {
      \foreach \j in {0,1} {
        \foreach \k in {0,1} {
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\ymax - (\ymax - \ymin) * (\k + 2*\j + 4*\i)/7.};
          \coordinate (-\i\j\k) at (0,\y);
          \node[xshift = 8pt] at (-\i\j\k) {$\i\j\k$};
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \pic(multi) [draw, fill = blue!20] {multiplexer};

  % select
  \coordinate (T) at ([yshift = 5pt]multi-NW);
  \foreach \s in {A,B,C} 
  \draw (multi-\s) -- (multi-\s |- T) node[above]{$\s$};

  % ground
  \coordinate (G) at (-1, 5);
  \draw[cyan] ([xshift = -3pt]G) -- ([xshift = 3pt]G);
  \foreach \n in {000,011,100,101} \draw[cyan] (multi-\n) -| (G);

  % in
  \coordinate (I) at (-0.5, 0);
  \draw[black] ([xshift = -3pt]I) -- ([xshift = 3pt]I) -- ([yshift =
  -5pt]I) -- cycle;
  \foreach \n in {001,010,110,111} \draw[black] (multi-\n) -| (I);

  % output
  \draw (multi-output) -- ++(0:0.5) node[right]{$Y$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]