# Define an edge style that get information from the nodes it is connected to

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to be able to define an edge that modify its properties according to some features of the nodes (for example the position of their anchor points). In general, I'm interested in how nodes and edges share information.
But, in particular, I'd like to automatize the answer  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247981/58947 probably defining a style for an edge to get something like

```
\draw[!-!] (A) edge (B);
```

where the "in" and "out" options for the edge are modified by the rotation angle of the nodes.

Comment: How should TikZ decide which side of the node it should connect to? What percusse has done in a `let … in` path specification can be hidden inside a `to path` (where one has access to the specified coordinates via `\tikztostart` and `\tikztotarget`, here `A` and `B` respectively).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You are right. In fact, I started thinking about that using the symbol 
[-]    ]-[  ]-]  [-[   but then I realized it could be stupid since square bracket are fundamental in TeX syntax, and I replaced them with !  probably too symmetric. What if one defines e.g. `!-!bt` and `!-!tb` ?

Comment: Thanks for the commands `\tikztostart` `\tikztotarget` I didn't know them!